# Jquery get true/false from php then run another ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am not good at JS, when the .btnStart clicked, i want it go "checkNULL" if ajax return sql "true - Don't have NULL column in 'end_time' entry", then go another ajax "startBooking", but the JS go to 'False - have NULL entry'.

JS here

```
$(".btnStart").click( function() {
var tid = $(this).data("tid")
$.get(
"",
{"ajax":"checkNULL", "tid":tid},
function(value){
    if (value === "true"){
        console.log('good'); //output
        $.get(
            "",
            {"ajax":"startBooking", "tid":tid},
            function(resp) {
                $(".sdate[data-tid="+tid+"]").val(resp.sdate).show().attr('disabled','disabled')                    
            },
            "JSON"
        )
        $(this).hide()
        $(".btnFinish[data-tid="+tid+"]").show()
    }else{
    console.log('bad'); //output
    }
},
"JSON")
```

PHP here

```
if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
if ($_GET['ajax'] == 'checkNULL') {
    $res = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tt where table_id=? AND end_time is NULL");
    $res->execute( [$_GET['tid']] );
    if ($user = $res->fetch()){
        if(trim($user['table_id']) == '' || trim($row['end_time']) == ''){
            return $value = "true"; // Don't have NULL entry
        }
            return $value = "false"; // have NULL entry
    }
    exit( json_encode($value));
}
elseif ($_GET['ajax'] == 'startBooking') {
    $dt = new DateTime('now');
    $start = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $st = $dt->format('H:i');
    $sd = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table_booking (table_id, start_time) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->execute( [ $_GET['tid'], $start ] );
    $bid = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    $resp = [ "bid" => $bid,
              "start" => $st,
              "sdate" => $sd
            ];
    exit( json_encode($resp));
}
```

Comment: Please describe what currently happens with this code, and what should happen. Your `return` in the PHP will result in just a string being sent, not JSON. Remove the `return` and let the `exit( json_encode($value));` execute if that is what you intend.

Comment: Well your code isn't that great and it is hard to find one thing that is wrong. I think you will not find a answer here, I would advise to debug a lot so you can atleast pinpoint **where** it goes wrong. For PHP, log 'tid' and the results of your db. Log your resp in JS.

Comment: If you encode with JSON, you'd also need to decode, or the answer will be ""true"" (doubled " ),
just add an console.log(value); before your IF clause, or just remove the json_encode in PHP, or decode it properly in JS.

Also that return in your script should throw errors. like you're returning (exiting the function) and then trying to echo the value, which will never be reached?

TL;DR you cannot return and exit / echo / die / etc. on the next line